# Basic misconception in tikz variable (node) names

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a 7-cycle, and I expect the following code to produce a 7-cycle with one edge missing.  However, the picture is completely messed up.

What happens in the lines

```
\pgfmathparse{\s - 1};
\draw (\s) -- (\pgfmathresult);
```

that I do not understand?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \def \n {7}
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
    \node (\s) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:1) {};
  }
  \foreach \s in {2,...,\n} 
  {
    \pgfmathparse{\s - 1};
    \draw (\s) -- (\pgfmathresult);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: broken 7-cycle]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It becomes a float from an integer. Then this float, say `3.0`, is parsed as

```
<node name>.<angle anchor>
```

like `(a.90)` etc. You can use `int(\s-1)` to truncate the decimal.

Answer (score 5):

As percusse says, the problem is that `\pgfmathresult` is producing `3.0` rather than `3`. Rather than computing `\s - 1`, an alternative solution would be to use the `remember` key. (See section 83 of the manual.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \def \n {7}
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
    \node (\s) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:1) {};
  }
  \foreach \s [remember=\s as \lasts (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n} 
  {
    \draw (\s) -- (\lasts);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or don't use `\pgfmathparse` ...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
  \def \n {7}
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    \node (\s) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:1) {};
\foreach [count=\sx from 1] \s in {2,...,\n}% <--- 
\draw (\s) -- (\sx);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```